# Sorting tuples in Python like dominoes/ finding vertex connectivity

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of integer tuples like this:

```
L=[(1,2),(7,6),(2,3),(8,5),(3,8),(5,7)]
```

Each pair defines an edge between two vertices and I want to find the vertex  connectivity. 
There are no loops, the tuples always uniquely link up like dominoes so in this case the sorted list should look like:

```
L_sorted=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,8),(8,5),(5,7),(7,6)]
```

Or alternatively

```
L_sorted=[1,2,3,8,5,7,6]
```

Is there an efficient way to do sorting like this in Python using predefined methods?

Comment: "Using predefined methods," you could check out [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/).

Comment: @blacksite Was trying with this networkx but such sorting works wrong there or couldn;t find appropriate function

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that any built-in facility can solve this. Third-party libraries might help. You can solve it in pure python:

```
L=[(1,2),(7,6),(2,3),(8,5),(3,8),(5,7)]
def domino(l):
    start = cursor = l[0][0]
    d = dict(l)
    while True:
        yield cursor
        try:
            cursor = d[cursor]
        except KeyError:
            # return here if your input may be non-cyclic.
            raise
        if cursor==start:
            return
x = list(domino(L))
# raises KeyError because 6 is dangling...
```

... or brew some C code using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: why noone can make it? neither me...

Answer (score -2):

Look at the built-in function `sorted`.